# Connected subset of a not connected set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be a connected subset of a metric space X. If X is not connected, it can be written as $X = M \cup N$ where $M$ and $N$ are disjoint, non-empty clopen sets. How can I show that either $A \subset M$ or $A \subset N$?

I tried proceeding by contradiction and writing $A = (A\cap M) \cup (A \cap N)$, but dont know what to do next (especially to show $A \cap M$ and $A \cap N$ are clopen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intersection of any open set in $X$ with $A$ is open in $A$ and intersection of any closed set in $X$ with $A$ is closed in $A$. Hence, $A\cap M$ and $A\cap N$ are clopen sets in $A$. Rest should be clear.

Comment: Thanks, I get the idea. However, is the statement in the first sentence always true? How could I prove it?

Comment: The definition of subspace topology says that a set is open in $A$ if it is the intersection with $A$ of an open set in $X$. For closed sets just note that $A \cap E^{c}$ is nothing but the complement in $A$ if $A \cap E$. @joeren1020

Comment: I haven't studied topology yet, so I only know open sets from the metric space perspective. Are these definitions equal?. Also, from the metric space perspective a subset of open set should also be open, right?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $A\cap M$ is non-empty. Then $A\cap M$ is clopen in $A$ because $M$ is clopen in $X$.

Comment: So, is the intersection of a clopen set with any set always clopen?

Comment: The intersection of a closed (open) set in the topology of $X$ with $A$ is closed (open) in the subset topology of $A$ induced from $X$.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume by contradiction that both $A\cap N$ and $A\cap M$ are non-empty, then you've found two clopen disjoint sets in $A$ (subspace topology) s.t $(A\cap N)\cup(A\cap M)=A$, contradiction to $A$ being connected.